# Не получается создать модель с атрибутом

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создал модель Project (все делаю как положено через `rails generate model Project title:string`):

```
validates :title, presence: true
has_many :todos
```

Создал модель Todo (`rails generate model Todo text:text isCompleted:boolean project:references`):

```
validates :text, presence: true
validates :isCompleted, presence: true
belongs_to :project
```

Произвел миграцию `rails db:migrate`.
Зашел в `rails console`, чтобы протестировать, но при попытке создать модель мне выдает ошибку:

```
2.4.1 :001 > project = Project.create title:"Мой проект"
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'title' for Project.
    from (irb):1
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180328121256) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "text"
    t.boolean "isCompleted"
    t.bigint "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_todos_on_project_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "todos", "projects"
end
```

20180328121057_create_projects.rb:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

20180328121256_create_todos.rb:

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.boolean :isCompleted
      t.references :project, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: (1) Для методов и связанных с ними сущностей обычно используют `snake_case` (это я про `isCompleted`); (2) что у вас в `db/schema.rb` (и потому, вероятнее всего, в БД)?

Comment: Я пересоздал проект и ничего не указывал в моделях после их генерации (только в модели Todo осталось belongs_to :project). project = Project.create title:"Мой проект" - теперь работает. Однако todo = Todo.create text:"some" сообщает мне:    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<Todo id: nil, text: "some", isCompleted: nil, project_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>. Содержание schema.rb добавил к записи, как и db.

Comment: Новые вопросы: почему не работает Todo.create и почему и можно ли как-то очистить базу уже созданных Project'ов (я заметил, что id новых созданных не обнуляется).

Answer (score 0):

Все заработало после удаления из модели Todo этой строчки:
'validates :isCompleted, presence: true'.
По какой-то причине validates в моделях не ладит с boolean и не хочет записывать значение false. Хотя возможно возможно есть и более правильно решение.

Comment: О. я знаю в чём дело. Не в моделях, нет. Почитайте: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

Answer (score 0):

Использовать presence для boolean полей не поддерживается. Вместо этого, если вы хотите проверять наличие логического поля (где значения являются `true` или `false`), решением будет использование **validates_inclusion_of**:

```
validates_inclusion_of :isCompleted, in: [true, false]
```

Оригинальная цитата из документации:

> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false].

[Документация](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)